# Как используя Python xlrd записать значения определенных столбцов в разные массивы?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Необходимо из файла xlsx вытащить значения определенных столбцов и записать их в разные массивы. У меня получилось пока только выводить значения определенных столбцов:

```
import xlrd

excel_data_file = xlrd.open_workbook('./testbook.xlsx')
sheet = excel_data_file.sheet_by_index(0)

row_number = sheet.nrows
col_number = sheet.ncols

for rownum in range(1, row_number):
    ku_ind = sheet.cell(rownum,0)
    sys_name = sheet.cell(rownum,2)
    print (ku_ind, sys_name)
```

Если я определяю `ku_ind` как массив (`ku_ind = []`), то при попытке вывода 1 элемента этого массива выдается сообщение

> TypeError: 'Cell' object does not support indexing.

Через `sheet.row_values(rownum)` тоже не получилось сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html), который использует `xlrd` по умолчанию для чтения XLSX файлов:

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

df = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/file.xlsx')
ku_ind_lst = df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
sys_name_lst = df.iloc[:, 2].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы прочитать значение одной ячейки используйте `sheet.cell_value()` вместо `sheet.cell()`.

Если вам надо прочитать все значения столбца в список, то лучше будет воспользоваться `sheet.col_values()`:

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\download\data\test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

ku_ind_lst = sheet.col_values(0)
sys_name_lst = sheet.col_values(2)
```

Comment: Очень помогли! Еще стал интересен такой момент, при анализе этих списков мне необходимо проверять 3 столбец на наличие элементов xxx, yyy, zzz и формировать список из элементов 1 столбца, которые соответствуют найденным xxx, yyy, zzz. Можно ли так делать: `for i in range(0, len(sys_name_lst)):
 if sys_name_lst[i] == 'xxx' and sys_name_lst[i] == 'yyy' and sys_name_lst[i] == 'zzz':
  b = sys_name_lst[i]
  c = ku_ind_lst[i]
  print(b)
  print(c)
`

Comment: @Maksecc, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814). По поводу нового вопроса лучше открыть отдельный SO вопрос со всеми детелями и небольшим примером входных и выходных данных